# Declare another template path for CreateView

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have 2 Apps in my django project , 1. HotelApp , 2. ManageHotels

The hotel details are shown to the user using the model in the HotelApp.

However I have set up a CreateView form in the ManageHotels app for owners to add Hotels.

> The problem is , CreateView attempts to find the form template inside

`HotelApp/templates/HotelApp/hotels_forms.html`

I would rather put hotels_forms.html in the `ManageHotels/templates/ManageHotels/hotels_forms.html`

> How do I change the template path ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could point to your desired path by specifying a 'template_name' on your CreateView. Something like:

```
class HotelCreate(CreateView):
template_name = 'ManageHotels/templates/ManageHotels/hotels_forms.html'
model = Hotel
fields = '__all__'
```

You would have to adjust the path accordingly. More on this on the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.template_name)